# need to convert data and time values to microtime

Tags: php, jquery, date-format

have a database with data and time

example: 2013-06-04 08:20:00

need to convert that to

example: 1378478351000

so i can add that number to jquery script event calendar

when i use this php code

```
$exc_date = $row_Recordset1['exc_date'];
$exc_date = microtime(true) *1000 ;
echo $exc_date;
```

it works right but it shows me the current date and time not the date and time saved at database,

can somone please help , thanks

Comment: How should this use the database value? You (re)set the variable to the result of the expression of `microtime(true) * 1000`. That is the current Unix timestamp with microseconds multiplied by 1000.

Comment: Try this ->$exc_date =strtotime( $row_Recordset1['exc_date']);
$exc_date1 =$ exc_date *1000 ;
echo $exc_date1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the calculations in PHP, add a computed column using `unix_timestamp` and `str_to_date` to your query:

```
select (
  unix_timestamp(str_to_date(TimeStrColumnName, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) * 1000) 
  as utime,  
# ... the rest of your query as before
```

if the MySQL column is already a date/time field (instead of a string), this will do it:

```
select (unix_timestamp(TimeStampColumnName) * 1000) as utime,  
# ... the rest of your query as before
```

Comment: why not directly converting to time?

Comment: The post doesn't specify the format of the SQL data. I'm guessing it's a string; you're guessing it's already a datetime field. I'll update the answer to account for both. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all for help, my database colomn is dateandtime format i have wrote the code "SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP, exec_date) * 1000) AS utime, FROM reservation"; but i'm getting error message says "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP'" is it because i'm running that at my offline server ?

Comment: No, you've just added an extra parameter ("TIMESTAMP") and an extra comma.  You want to say `select (unix_timestamp(exec_date) * 1000) as utime from reservation;`

Comment: now after correcting that to "SELECT (unix_timestamp(exc_date) * 1000) AS utimes FROM reservation"; i'm getting message says "Undefined index: utime"

Comment: You have `utimes` in your select, so I imagine `utime` (without the "s") *would* be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does, as you overwrite the database values in the second line by putting microtime instead in it.

You will not be able to get the microtime, when you just have the format of date in the database - so you should use 0. microtime is returning the value of the actual microtime at the moment.

You should do something like that to get time + microtime:

```
$exec_date = strtotime($row_Recordset1[exec_date"]) . "000";
```

More information [here](https://www.php.net/strtotime). The problem with this is, that you will get it as a string, so you will need to convert it to an integer:

```
$exec_date = (int) $exec_date;
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Technically you should be doing `* 1000` instead of a concatenation, since strtotime returns an int, but doing the concat will probably help protect against integer overflow, especially on 32bit PHP installs.